# Why does `script.py <(cat *.gz)` work with subprocess.Popen in python 2 but not python 3?

Tags: python, subprocess, process-substitution

We discovered recently that a script we developed chokes in python 3.x (but not python 2.x) if it is supplied its input files via process substitution, e.g.:

```
script.py <(cat *.gz)
```

We've tested with commands other than gzip, such as cat, just to see if we get a similar error.  They all complain that `/dev/fd/63` (or `/dev/fd/63.gz`) does not exist.  Here's the (simplified) relevant bit of code:

```
def open_gzip_in(infile):
    '''Opens a gzip file for reading, using external gzip if available'''

    # Determine whether to use the gzip command line tool or not
    if exeExists('gzip'):
        cmd = ['gzip', '-dc', infile]
        p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=-1,
                             universal_newlines=True)
        if sys.version.startswith("2"):
            with p.stdout:
                for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, b''):
                    yield line
        else:
            with p:
                for line in p.stdout:
                    yield line
        exit_code = p.wait()
        if exit_code != 0:
            raise subprocess.CalledProcessError(
                p.returncode, subprocess.list2cmdline(cmd), 'Ungzip failed')
    else:
        with io.TextIOWrapper(io.BufferedReader(gzip.open(infile))) as f:
            for line in f:
                yield(line)
```

*Incidentally, we do the fork simply because the command line gzip is significantly faster than using gzip.open and our script is a long-running worker - the difference is multiple hours.*

We are implementing a work-around for this issue, but would like to understand why it doesn't work in python 3 but does work in python 2.

Comment: BTW, if decompression speed is that costly for you, you might think about an algorithm other than gzip. See the benchmarks in https://facebook.github.io/zstd/

Comment: Gzip isn’t our choice. It’s used by a system our script runs in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a side effect of the new default `Popen()`-family argument `close_fds=True`. You can explicitly override it with `close_fds=False`, and your inherited file descriptors will be passed through to the child process (subject to configuration via `os.set_inheritable()`).

Similarly, on Python 3.2 and later, you can use the `pass_fds` list, as in, `pass_fds=[0,1,2,63]`, to make stdin, stdout, stderr, and FD #63 available to the subprocess invoked.